# Rotate x-axis labels, D3js multi bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I would like to rotate my labels on the x-axis. The labels are currently overlapping. However, I can't figure out how to alter them in the template I based the bar chart off of. My assumption is that it is somewhere in the lines below, but it is a template with a structure I am unfamiliar with as a d3 beginner. My plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/jtGz8vtYGSHscKhrIob3?p=preview

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    return d;
}, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

    x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.n; }));
    x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();



    var rectG = g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.n) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When appending the x-axis, you can do the following to rotate the labels:

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x0))
    //select all text labels in the axis, then position + rotate
    .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-1em")
      .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
```

PS: this will overlap with all the text/labels you have in the bottom and you have to position them accordingly as well so things fit properly. You probably have to stretch out your `svg` a little bit vertically to make everything fit. I have given it a try in the plunkr; you can adjust it further if you want the graph to be larger, etc.

Forked Plunkr here - http://plnkr.co/edit/JyFdeX0wy9g0lUKi9ASC?p=preview

Comment: This makes sense! I didn't realise you could create a new g.append and have that control the angle of the x-axis labels. This should help a lot for some other charts I'm making. Thank you for the solution (and repositioning as well)! =p